# Может ли бот отличить группу от личных сообщений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Хотел спросить. Каким образом Бот может отличить группу от личных сообщений? Например, присутствует команда, работающая только в личных сообщениях, а при попытке использовать ее в группе, бот подсказывал, что команда работает только в личных сообщениях.

Comment: есть отдельно типы сообщений...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если chat id будет отрицательным, то это группа.